# Is there a best practice for binding JPA Entity fields directly to JSF components?

Tags: jsf, jpa

I find myself going back and forth on this.  For simple POJO's, binding simple fields to components is usually fairly straightforward:

```
<h:outputText value="#{myPage.user.name}"/>
<h:outputText value="#{myPage.user.birthday}">
    <f: ....
```

But, when it comes to managing Collections or Objects, I've found myself wanting a "wrapper" Object which can be more easily managed.  For example, managing a Collection in a POJO requires (at least in JSF 2.1) wrapping it in a DataModel or List.  Therefore the wrapping object will have getters/setters/actionListeners to help facilitate the management.

Now that JSF 2.2 has come along though, you can actually map Collections to JSF components...so it seems like JSF is making it more and more easier to map directly to the Entities.

I'd like to be consistent though.  Do people generally map to the Entity as much as possible and then use wrapper methods in their pages to manage the exceptions?  Or do you wrap the whole object use that with your component bindings?

Comment: In my opinion, there's no problem in using entities as far as you can. Just perform the data access in action/initializer methods instead of doing it in the setters. Then you can implement a try/catch block inside where you can control the exceptions and add a Faces Message if one of them happens. However, you'll need to ensure JPA isn't closing the session after the action method, this could end up in `LazyInitalizationException` in managed bean getter methods.

Answer (score 0):

One size does not fit all scenarios, directly binding entity beans to pages is possible with several frameworks, but is not necessarily a good idea. A simple project can benefit from the immediacy of direct binding, but it is easy to run into situations that dictate exceptions to this rule.

The reason behind this is that UI is not necessarily an exact representation of the backing entities (i.e., the info you enter into input fields does not fit exactly into entity fields and require transformation). Suppose a simple example, you could need to put the value of three different input fields (like day, month and year of a date) into a single field in the entity with `java.util.Date` type. This is a case in which UI does not match the backing data model. Constraining either one, or both, to adapt to the constraints of the other is not a good solution (in the example, you either change the three input fields into a single one, or worse yet change the entity bean to have three columns to store the date).

This type of problems is usually solved introducing a layer that isolates between the data model and the view, in the form of DTOs or similar data-carrying objects that handle differences in mappings (again from the example, you have a DTO that provides the three fields to store the deconstructed date and synthesizes a `java.util.Date` object by combining the three values.

In JSF many of these concerns can be addressed with the use of converters, but these solutions can be difficult to maintain (you change a page and you find yourself having to change the converter). Also some use cases are too complex to handle in converters (for example collections).

In a nutshell, the answer is "it depends". Simpler applications with simple interactions and UI requirements can safely use direct binding. More complex applications usually require more separation between the tiers and additional functionality that direct binding cannot address.

Comment: Thanks Emir.  This is basically the conclusion I've come up with.  I'm just torn between doing this all the same way or leaving it different depending upon the circumstance.  Having all these different idioms in my code is setting off my OCD a bit though!

Comment: What you usually want to do is not mix both in the same project. It is ok to go for direct binding only if it is used in the entire project, if you have a complex use case then it is safer to go directly for DTOs in the entire project.

Comment: It's all one big project.  I just hate wrapping a POJO with 20 fields just because 1-2 of them can't be directly bound to a component.  So much unnecessary getter/setter boilerplate...

Comment: I agree with the 'it depends' I personally try to do as little 'DTO' stuff as possible. E.g. regarding your second and third paragraph, solutions like http://balusc.blogspot.nl/2013/01/composite-component-with-multiple-input.html are very useful and could be used in multiple projects if you make it generic (maybe it could be added to a jsf component framework). And can you please explain why you using converters is difficult to maintain? How would e.g. changing the page result in changing the converter?

Comment: Oh, and I'd appreciate an example of a use case where you'd initially think of using a converter to handle collections but where it eventually is impossible. I am trying to think of one, but fail to come up with something (I usually handle complex things that are collections in a datatable or `ui:repeat`

Comment: @Kukeltje Are you saying that handling collections can be done by using a simple converter?  I had not thought about that approach.  Not quite sure how you would do that though. Assuming we are talking about JSF 2.1, are you saying you could bind a Collection to the selectManyListbox value attribute with a converter??

Comment: No, I'm saying that I never tried to use JSF Converters at all with collections (I did use http://showcase.omnifaces.org/functions/Converters which is a solution for your case to I think). But I also did not resort to using DTO's in any way for this but sometimes a wrapper method

Comment: @Kukeltje: I'm not saying that it is impossible to use converters, I'm saying it could be convoluted and difficult to maintain. One simple example from a previous project: a page in which I need to maintain three lists, one with the list of roles assigned to a user, a second with the list of roles available but not assigned and a third with the list of roles not directly assigned but inherited from assigned roles. When you add a new role to the list of available ones, you have to update the list of transitive roles inherited.

Comment: You also need to update the list of available roles, removing the role added plus all roles inherited which cannot be assigned anymore. It is not that you cannot do this with converters, my precise point is that it was done with a converter and after a few months it had to be changed to a DTO.

Comment: Sorry, 'impossible' was a wrong choice of words (to strong). I see the use case, but isn't that something that should be handled by a service and not by a converter or DTO? If a converter is something to change e.g. an entity to an id to use in a select or something, I fail to see how a converter plays an active role in more than just this unless it is 'abused'. That is why I asked for an example since you mentioned it so explicitly in your answer. But my knowledge is limited so I might miss something.

Comment: You can use a service to maintain the graph of roles and the transitive closure but since each displayed list is different you cannot store the actual lists with data in the service itself. Thus you need to put the partial lists somewhere, you could create some transient fields in the entity itself, or use a separate specialized class for that. My point is that if you start putting visualization-specific code in the jpa entity, things start getting confusing and is difficult to keep track of what is persistent and what isn't.

Comment: @EmirCalabuch: Agree with your last comment, but that is a much clearer answer than in your real answer. Maybe add something to it. I mostly store the partial/transient lists in a managed bean...